# Finding the group of limit points

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Find the set of limit points in $$\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$$

I understand that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $r>0$ there is $y\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y\in B(x,r)$.

Why does the set of all limit points is said to be  $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: well, you answered yourself already. How did you define a limit point? Compare this with what you've written after "I understand that..."

Comment: Let $\Bbb Q'$ be the set of all limit points of $\Bbb Q$. As what you already said, we have $\Bbb R\subset \Bbb Q'$ and hence,  $\Bbb R= \Bbb Q'$

Comment: @sranthrop that is the problem, I am trying to understand the definition

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Ok I think I got it! the x's are the limit points and not the y's right?

Comment: Yes, of course. If $x\in\Bbb R$ then as what you said $x\in\Bbb Q'$. The $y$ is used to show that the ball $B(x,r)$ contains a point (which is $y$) in $\Bbb Q$ other than $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, a limiting point of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $x \in X$ with $x \in B(a, \varepsilon)$, where $B(a, \varepsilon)$ denotes the set of points in $\mathbb{R}$ with distance less than $\varepsilon$ to $a$.

As you wrote, to every point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|a-q| < \varepsilon$ 
("every real number can be approximated by rational numbers").
Thus $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of limiting points of $\mathbb{Q}$.